# Do entity framework object references equal for same database objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Does entity framework return the same object reference if I query the "logically" (in database) same object from different places.

For example, I queried customer with name Joe Black, (and assume for now I know that there's only one Joe Black in the database.)
`Customer c = select ... blabla where ... Name == Joe Black...;` and in somewhere else in the code, I queried `Customer c2 = select... where.. ID==5` where 5 is the ID of Joe Black. I know that in the database they map to the same object, but DO they also map to the same object in code level? So does c1 equal to c2? I have lists to merge and check for logical equality of the objects (I cannot access the database for now) and I was wondering whether Entity Framework objects will play nicely with it or should I write my custom comparer classes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most ORMs, including Entity Framework and NHibernate, use the [Identity Map Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) to ensure there is only a single instance of a given entity per primary key. The identity map is scoped by the context, so two different contexts will create two objects which refer to the same entity. It is a good practice to have entities implement IEquatable, including overrides for equality operators so that '==' or '!=' will work. This is more involved than what one might think. Take a look [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/identity-field-equality-and-hash-code.aspx) for an example.

Comment: That answered by question, thank you. So it means my job is easier, but I don't know how to add implement methods or overload operators for Entity Framework-automatically generated classes. Anyway, got access to my DB again and it worked. So EF handles that as well.