# EF6 Equality/Equals with key field vs object equality

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using the same context, so my entities [should always be equatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542700/do-entity-framework-object-references-equal-for-same-database-objects) in code. Is it then better to use:

```
if (instance1 == instance2) //...
```

or

```
if (instance1.id == instance2.id) //...
```

i.e. which is faster? Presumably the hashcode - i.e. option 1?